# Why does Node util.inspect() append ^M to every line before newline?

Tags: node.js, carriage-return, linefeed

Why does node.js now (as of version 6.4.0) append `^M` to each line that is output from `require('util').inspect()`? This seems wrong on any platform that doesn't use CR as a line delimiter (e.g., most of the ones node runs well on).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an errant commit in node.js v6.4.0.

The change is being reverted.
See [this](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/8143) for more info.